# MySQL create field on main table with concatenated rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Input two table, `TABLE A` and `TABLE B`

```
 TABLE A       TABLE B
 A_ID |   A    A_ID |  B        
    1 |   a       1 |  b
    2 |  a1       1 | b1
    3 |  a2       2 | b2
```

Expecting Output `TABLE C`

```
 TABLE C
 A_ID |  A | C
    1 |  a | b,b1  <--- Concat all rows in TABLE B with ','
    2 | a1 | b2
    3 | a2 | NULL  <--- NULL if no matched A_ID in TABLE B
```

Column C finds all matched A_ID and concat All rows of B in to new TEXT field.
Can this be done only with MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into TABLE_C 
SELECT 
      A1.A_ID, 
      A1.A, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(B1.B) as 'C'
    FROM `TABLE_A` A1 
    LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B` B1 
    ON A1.A_ID=B1.A_ID 
    GROUP BY A1.A_ID;
```

*left join on above sql helps to get the common matching (relating) rows from two tables 'TABLE_A' and 'TABLE_B' and group by id helps to get the rows which are not not matched (not relate to each other which returns the result set for 2,a1 and 3,null). group_concat bind two columns and by default it is comma separated . If we want some other separator then only we need to used group_concat with separator statement. And also insert select helps to insert a results row into a new table 'TABLE_C' which is ofcourse need to created on prior*

Comment: Perhaps you could give some explanation as to how/why this works?

Comment: left join on above sql helps to get the common matching (relating) rows from two tables 'TABLE_A' and 'TABLE_B' and group by id helps to get the rows which are not not matched (not relate to each other which returns the result set for 2,a1 and 3,null). @john
group_concat bind two columns and by default it is comma separated . If we want some other separator then only we need to used group_concat with separator  statement.

And also insert select helps to insert a results row into a new table 'TABLE_C' which is ofcourse  need to created  on prior.

Comment: **Edit** your answer to add this clarification, do not use comments to clarify your answer as it should be an integral part of your answer.

Comment: Your answer already solved my problem, Thanks. How do I order by the column C in TABLE_C? ORDEY BY C IS NULL DESC does not seems to work.

Comment: @Clinton Lam  **select * from TABLE_C order by C desc** should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

```
SELECT 
  tbla.A_ID, 
  tbla.A, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(tblb.B) 
FROM `TABLE A` tbla 
LEFT JOIN `TABLE B` tblb 
ON tbla.A_ID=tblb.A_ID 
GROUP BY tbla.A_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [group_contact](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to aggregate values of column B in TABLE B within a group. Insertion of values to TABLE C can be done using [INSERT .. SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
insert into tablec 
select a.a_id, a.a, group_concat(b separator ',') 
from tablea a 
left join tableb b on (a.a_id = b.a_id) 
group by a.a_id, a.a;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.